# Problem With Setting Compiler Flags

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

I'm trying to configure my cross compiler (mipseb-linux-g++) to generate binaries with the MIPSI ISA.  There is a flag for this "-mips1".  I have this flag in my make file and for some reason g++ is still generating MIPSII instructions (which I assume is default?).  Am I doing anything wrong?  Here's my process flow:

- write c++ program
- compile using mipseb-linux-g++
- generate a hex dump with mipseb-linux-objdump
- look in HEX dump to see if there are any MIPS II instructions (like beqzl)

Here is my makefile:

```
##############################################################################
#  \author acc@cs.rochester.edu
#  \version 0.01
#  \brief
##############################################################################

# Environment variables which should already be set in your path
# ACC_PATH ?= $(shell `pwd | awk 'BEGIN{FS="benchmarks/acc"} {print $1}'`)
# BENCHDIR ?= $(ACC_PATH)/benchmarks
# SESCSOURCEDIR ?= $(ACC_PATH)/sesc
# SESCBUILDDIR ?= $(ACC_PATH)/build
XTOOLSPREFIX ?= /home/seas/grad/dasnyder/cmplrs

##############################################################################

# Compiler and linker
CC     = $(XTOOLSPREFIX)/bin/mipseb-linux-gcc
CXX    = $(XTOOLSPREFIX)/bin/mipseb-linux-g++
LD     = $(XTOOLSPREFIX)/bin/mipseb-linux-gcc
AR     = $(XTOOLSPREFIX)/bin/mipseb-linux-ar
RANLIB = $(XTOOLSPREFIX)/bin/mipseb-linux-ranlib

# Common compiler flags
CFLAGS = -O3 -funroll-loops -fsched-interblock \
         -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -funroll-loops \
         -mips1 -mabi=32 -mtune=r2000 -static -Wa,-non_shared \
         -mno-abicalls -fno-PIC -freduce-all-givs \
         -I. -I$(XTOOLSPREFIX)/mipseb-linux/include

# C++ flags
CXXFLAGS = ${CFLAGS} -I$(XTOOLSPREFIX)/mipseb-linux/include/c++/3.2 \
         -I$(XTOOLSPREFIX)/mipseb-linux/include/c++/3.2/mips-linux-gnu \
         -mips1 -mabi=32 -mtune=r2000 -msoft-float -funroll-loops \
         -fdelayed-branch

# Common linker flags
# LDFLAGS = -Wl,--script=$(SESCSOURCEDIR)/src/libapp/mint.x \
#         -L$(SESCBUILDDIR)/obj/mipseb_obj -L$(XTOOLSPREFIX)/mipseb-linux/lib

LDFLAGS = -L$(XTOOLSPREFIX)/mipseb-linux/lib -lstdc++ -lm


# Common libs
LIBS    =

# Common definitions
DEFS    =

# Emacs tags
EMACSTAGS = TAGS
```

Comment: What version of g++? What is the actual output of make?

Comment: Version 3.2,  the output of make is the following:
/home/seas/grad/dasnyder/cmplrs/bin/mipseb-linux-g++ -O3 -funroll-loops -fsched-interblock -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -funroll-loops -mips1 -mabi=32 -mtune=r2000 -static -Wa,-non_shared -mno-abicalls -fno-PIC -freduce-all-givs -I. -I/home/seas/grad/dasnyder/cmplrs/mipseb-linux/include -I/home/seas/grad/dasnyder/cmplrs/mipseb-linux/include/c++/3.2 -I/home/seas/grad/dasnyder/cmplrs/mipseb-linux/include/c++/3.2/mips-linux-gnu -mips1 -mabi=32 -mtune=r2000 -msoft-float -funroll-loops -fdelayed-branch helloworld.cpp -o helloworld

Comment: I wonder if the linker is pulling in MIPS II objects. Do your .o files contain the offending instructions?

Comment: As far as I understand my output file is "helloworld" which is the file that I'm disassembling with objdump.  Is this wrong?  Sorry, I'm somewhat of a novice.  After dis-assembly of the "helloworld" file the offending instructions are visible.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is actually my makefile: include Makefile.common
all:
        ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} helloworld.cpp -o helloworld

It includes the file shown in the thread.

Comment: This looks like a compiler issue and not a Makefile issue.  If you are using an r2000 processor and want to limit the output to that then you may want to drop -mips1 and explicitly force -march=r2000 -mabi=32 -mtune=r2000 and see how the compiler reacts.  There are a lot of controls available for MIPS, have a look at the gcc man page under MIPS.

Comment: You are disassembling the right thing... I would suggest that you actually disassemble the object file rather than the final linked binary.

So really the result of:

    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o helloworld.o helloworld.cpp 

    objdump -d helloworld.o

Comment: What is the distinction? (aside from the file name)  Also, when I replace -mips1 with -march=r2000 I get an assembler warning that says that it could not set the architecture and machine.  Are you familiar with this issue?

Comment: Your suggestion about disassembling the object file was correct.  This does not contain any MIPS II instructions.  I don't quite understand why helloworld.o and helloworld are compiled using different instruction sets though.

Comment: Actually, the disassembly of the object file doesn't yield the hex dump I need.  In fact, the object file only contains a small portion of the binary.  There are several non-references labels in the object file.  Where do the rest of the instructions go?  I don't even see a syscall in the object file.  And this is a HelloWorld program I'm testing with.